# How does NumPy seed its random number generators if no seed is provided?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

For example, suppose I call `numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)` without calling any of the seed-related functions. NumPy must be using some default seed, but I couldn't find it in the documentation. How does NumPy seed its random numbers when no seed is specified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For NumPy's legacy `numpy.random.*` functions, including `numpy.random.uniform`, a global [`RandomState` object initialized with no arguments](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L4566) is used. Because a seed isn't passed to this `RandomState`, "the MT19937 BitGenerator is initialized by reading data from `/dev/urandom` (or the Windows analogue) if available or seed from the clock otherwise" (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html#numpy.random.RandomState).

Likewise, NumPy's newer `BitGenerator` classes, such as `PCG64`, are seeded by default with "fresh, unpredictable entropy ... pulled from the OS" (example for [`default_rng`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng)).