# How a random number is generated in Numpy if I don't use Generator or RandomState?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-random

I have read the Doc of Numpy,but I still don't know how a random number is generated if I don't use Generator or RandomState.
As far as I know,we can get a random number from 1 to 10 by

```py
#use RandomState
print(np.random.RandomState().randint(1,10,(1)))
#use Generator
print(np.random.default_rng().randint(1,10,(1)))
#my question
print(np.random.default_rng().integers(1,10,(1)))
```

So how the random number is generated in the third way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does NumPy seed its random number generators if no seed is provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092967/how-does-numpy-seed-its-random-number-generators-if-no-seed-is-provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This targets the first version of the question)

There is just a `RandomState` created *globally* at start/import/load-time.

See [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9f12028b9453c17b72b26355fd503e512af96a5d/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L4566)

More to read in this discussion: [Public access to global state for numpy.random](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15322)